# How to prevent Amazon S3 from creating files randomly?

Tags: amazon-s3

I just setup a new Amazon S3 Bucket (my first one). And everything works fine, but.. It's creating random files:

e.g. a file named as `2013-07-16-11-15-52-F48E3174FF2FD2C2`

What is this? How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Those are most likely Amazon S3 logging files - try disabling through the Management Console as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/ManagingBucketLogging.html).